# Can't seem to add extra sheets to 4 page schematic design

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I have an existing 4 page schematic I need to add an extra page too (see picture).  I can't figure out how to to add an additional page, how does one do this?

My version is Eagle 9.0.1 on Windows 10.

Thanks if anyone can help.

[image: 4 sheets only]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do this using GUI, but you can run command EDIT .sX where X is a sheet number higher than last existing sheet. It will create a new one for you.

It won't help if you reached the sheet limit of your edition though. Try creating a new schematics and right-click there again. If "New" is not grayed out anymore that would be the case.

Comment: OK I ran "EDIT .s5" and it showed the message I was at the max. # of sheets for my version, so I just need to upgrade.  Problem solved.

Comment: Not really solved, I am afraid. They don't even have 4-sheet edition anymore :( Free one is 2, and the rest are now by yearly subscription. I am so frustrated that I did not update to the last version prior to introduction of subscription model.

Comment: Beware readers also if you encounter this problem.  It took quite a few hours after I purchased the $100 version for the auth. to go through and Eagle to unlock the > 4 sheet capability.